# WKWebview Android Alternative

Tags: android, hybrid-mobile-app, wkwebview

I'd like to know if there is a WKWebView alternative for Android? I'm asking this because all hybrid apps I made worked great on Apple's WKWebView, while not working that good on Android.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have not ever used WKWebView, but is there some problem with using [Android's built-in WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)? Regardless, from my brief googling, I keep finding references to [a project called Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/). Maybe that will prove useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the [Telerik WKWebView plugin github repository](https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/WKWebView/issues/57),

> WKWebView is something created by Apple, specific to iOS, that this
>   plugin takes advantage of. It doesn’t exist on Android. The closest
>   thing similar to it would be Crosswalk.

Here you can find all the relevant information about the Crosswalk project,

https://crosswalk-project.org/